# Explanation of "weight function" of inner product in Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I am a physicist so I am sorry if the following is not written in a rigorous (or even completely right) way.
As Quantum Mechanics is formed in Hilbert space, I would like to know what the so-called weight function $w(t)$ stands for, which is defined via the inner product:
$$
 \langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(t) \overline{g(t)} w(t) \,\text{d}t.
$$
In vectors in finite dimensions, the inner product does not need something analogous to this, it is just the sum of the multiplication of the components of the vectors in each "direction", so why do we need this in infinite dimensions? What is the use of it? And, **most importantly**  ,when do we need to have w(t) not equal to 1?
I am only at my second year, so I don't know a lot of mathematics, so a fairly simple but intuitive explanation would be ideal. I would appreciate it if you could connect the explanation with vectors in finite dimensions as I know a fair amount of undergraduate linear algebra, so I can visualize or create useful analogies.

Comment: You don't *need* the weight function either in finite or infinite dimensions, but you *can* include it in either case.  An inner product creates a geometry on a vector space, and in finite dimensions, you can see adding the weight function as "distorting" that geometry in a linear way (e.g. stretching in some directions more than others).  Maybe the same analogy is helpful for infinite dimensions.

Comment: Adding a weight to the Euclidean inner product on a finite dimensional space doesn't affect metric and topological results in any substantial way.  But in infinite dimensions it does.  Each inner product produces a norm with which you can measure whether a sequence is bounded or not.  In finite dimensions a sequence that is bounded for one weight will be bounded for all other weights.  In infinite dimensions this is not the case, for example take $w_1\equiv 1$ and $w_2(t)=1/t^{1/2}$ and the sequence of functions $f_n(t)=1/t^{(n-4)/4n}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide more context regarding where you have met a weight function in Quantum Mechanics, someone might comment about the physical meaning.

For motivation, recall that even on a finite dimensional vector space, there are many different possible inner products on a single vector space - not only the standard one. A choice of an inner product on a vector space $V$ defines the lengths of vectors and the (cosine of) angles between two vectors and there are infinitely many possible choices each determining a different orthonormal basis for $V$.

Consider the following simple model: instead of thinking of vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ as tuples of $n$ complex numbers, think about them as functions from the finite set $\{1, \ldots, n \}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ so elements of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are identified with functions $f \colon \{ 1, \ldots, n \} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Then, the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is written as

$$ \left< f, g \right> = \sum_{i=1}^n f(i) \overline{g(i)}. $$

If we are given a "weight" function $w \colon \{ 1, \ldots, n \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, we can define a new inner product

$$ \left< f, g \right>_w := \sum_{i=1}^n f(i) \overline{g(i)} w(i). $$

Denote by $e_i$ the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Measured using the standard inner product, the vectors $(e_i)$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$. Measured using the alternative inner product $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_w$, the vectors $(e_i)$ are still orthogonal but not orthonormal anymore - the length of each $e_i$ is $\sqrt{\left< e_i, e_i \right>_w} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{w_i}}$.

Sometimes, the freedom in choosing some convenient inner product on $V$ is useful. Let's assume that you have some linear operator $T \colon V \rightarrow V$. If we could choose some inner product on $V$ (not necessarily the "standard" one, if there is some notion of "standard" for $V$) with respect to which $T$ would be self adjoint, we can apply the spectral theorem and deduce that $T$ is orthogonally diagonalizable (with respect to the chosen inner product). Modulo some technicalities, this precisely what happens in infinite dimensional setting for the the [Sturm-Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) equation in which you have a second order differential eigenvalue problem you want to solve and under a choice of an inner product with a weight function, the relevant operator becomes self-adjoint and you can apply general results about self-adjoint operators to deduce the existence of an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, we can choose the weight function or is it determined by our problem?

Comment: Usually, the problem dictates the appropriate weight function.

Comment: So, the problem that dictates the weight function, essentially changes the mathematical space(sorry for any sluggish language here) in which the inner product takes place. So, where does it all fit in physics(in case you know). Also, what is the intuition behind the reason for that change of the geometry of that space? Why would we need to change its geometry in order for the inner product to be correct?

Comment: The point is that the problem often dictates the geometry (inner product), the appropriate mathematical space in which we should formulate the problem. Consider for example the problem of finding the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^3$ which appears in quantum mechanics in the analysis of the hydrogen atom. Since the problem has spherical symmetry, it suggests that we should move to spherical coordinates obtaining separation of variables. Then we analyze the eigenfunctions of the spherical Laplacian of a function $f(\theta, \varphi)$.

Comment: So, where does the reason of needing a change in the geometry come in your example?

Comment: Now, $\theta$ and $\varphi$ are the spherical coordinates and the appropriate inner product here takes in the account the geometry of the sphere - it should be modified by a "weight" function (which is the volume form of the sphere). That is, $\left< f, g \right> = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} f(\theta, \varphi) \overline{g(\theta,\varphi)} \sin (\theta) \, d \theta d \phi$. This is not a weight function per se (as $\sin(\theta)$ is not positive) but you get the idea. With this specific choice of the inner product, the spherical Laplacian becomes self-adjoint.

Comment: @levap But for inner product between vectors we don't use a weight function. Why we must do this for functions?

Comment: @user599310: First of all, sometimes you use a weight function also for inner products of vectors. Whenever you compute the inner product of two vectors given in polar coordinates, you actually use a "weight function" in disguise. You can usually hide it by choosing appropriate orthonormal bases and then you can work "just as if" there are no weights but in some sense, they are there. In the infinite dimensional setting, the choice of the weight function dictates the space you are working on so it becomes more of an issue but you "mustn't" do anything, it completely depends on the setting.

Comment: @levap To be fair though, if the basis is truly not orthonormal, then with no other assumptions, $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle=w_{ij}$ would hold in the discrete analogy, which would translate to $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(t)\bar{g}(u)w(t, u)\ dt\ du$.
And now I'm wondering if any such $w(t, u)$ can correspond to something like a Hilbert space with non-zero intrinsic curvature (from differential geometry).

Comment: This is an absolutely fabulous answer, I cannot thank you enough ( I had the same question)